# C# CSOM - Check if File Exists in Document Library

Tags: c#, sharepoint, office365, csom

I'm coding in C# using CSOM, my app uploads a template asp.net page to the "/Pages/" library, I need it to check if a file exists in that location with the same name prior to file upload (then maybe it can return a bool value).

I did have a quick look but the majority of the solutions I found referred to the use of Javascript, or applied to on-prem deployments.

If someone could please point me in the right direction I would appreciate it.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You could consider the following approaches to determine whether file exists or not.

### Query based

You could construct CAML query to find list item by its Url as demonstrated below:

```
public static bool FileExists(List list, string fileUrl)
{
    var ctx = list.Context;
    var qry = new CamlQuery();
    qry.ViewXml = string.Format("<View Scope=\"RecursiveAll\"><Query><Where><Eq><FieldRef Name=\"FileRef\"/><Value Type=\"Url\">{0}</Value></Eq></Where></Query></View>",fileUrl);
    var items = list.GetItems(qry);
    ctx.Load(items);
    ctx.ExecuteQuery();
    return items.Count > 0;
}
```

Usage

```
using (var ctx = GetSPOContext(webUri,userName,password))
{
     var list = ctx.Web.Lists.GetByTitle(listTitle);
     if(FileExists(list,"/documents/SharePoint User Guide.docx"))
     {
          //...
     }
}
```

### `Web.GetFileByServerRelativeUrl` Method

Use [Web.GetFileByServerRelativeUrl Method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.client.web.getfilebyserverrelativeurl%28v=office.15%29.aspx) to return the file object located at the specified server-relative URL.

If file does not exists the exception [Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ServerException](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.client.serverexception.aspx) will be encountered:

```
  public static bool TryGetFileByServerRelativeUrl(Web web, string serverRelativeUrl,out Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.File file)
    {
        var ctx = web.Context;
        try{
            file = web.GetFileByServerRelativeUrl(serverRelativeUrl);
            ctx.Load(file);
            ctx.ExecuteQuery();
            return true;
        }
        catch(Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ServerException ex){
            if (ex.ServerErrorTypeName == "System.IO.FileNotFoundException")
            {
                file = null;
                return false;
            }
            else
                throw;
        }
    }
```

Usage:

```
 using (var ctx = GetSPOContext(webUri,userName,password))
 {
      Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.File file;
      if(TryGetFileByServerRelativeUrl(ctx.Web,"/documents/SharePoint User Guide.docx",out file))
      {
          //...
      }
 }
```

Comment: The query based solution works perfectly. Between the two - what's the difference? Why would you use one over the other? Thanks again!

Comment: I would also prefer query based approach over the second one. But in some cases you could gain benefits using the second approach from performance perspective

Comment: For the Web.GetFileByServerRelativeUrl Method, note that you will probably need to specify more than just "/documents/doc.docx" if your site is sitting at a folder level below the top of the url.
I had to specify everything after the hostname... for example "/sites/dept/hr/subsitename/documents/doc.docx"

Answer (score 11):

An alternative to the Web.GetFileByServerRelativeUrl (@vadim posted above) is `Load(checkFile, p => p.Exists);` and in context ...

```
using (ClientContext ctx = new ClientContext("https://yoursubdomainhere.sharepoint.com/"))
{
    Web web = ctx.Web;
    Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.File checkFile = web.GetFileByServerRelativeUrl("/sites/Documents/MyFile.docx");

    ctx.Load(checkFile, fe => fe.Exists);
    ctx.ExecuteQuery();
    if (!checkFile.Exists)
    {
        //Do something here
    }
}
```

Comment: Agreed. What usually breaks the check is actually ctx.Load(file) because the file object can't be loaded if it doesn't exist. You have it right by loading only the Exists property.

Comment: tried this approach and i got  `Exists` property without any exception for valid and invalid file names.

Comment: Works perfectly well. I think it is best answer because it does not use any blind exception traps as others suggest here.

Answer (score 8):

if you are using Client OM, it would actually throw an exception if the file doesn't exist:

```
using(var clientContext = new ClientContext(site))
{
     Web web = clientContext.Web;
     Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.File file = web.GetFileByServerRelativeUrl("/site/doclib/folder/filename.ext");
     bool bExists = false;
     try
     {
         clientContext.Load(file);
         clientContext.ExecuteQuery(); //Raises exception if the file doesn't exist
         bExists = file.Exists;  //may not be needed - here for good measure
     }
     catch{   }

     if (bExists )
     {
           .
           .
     }
}
```

[Resource](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/359672/how-to-determine-if-a-file-exists-in-a-sharepoint-spfolder/8011028#8011028)

Answer (score 4):

Using Linq To SharePoint

```
    public bool FolderExists(string library, string name) {

        using (var ctx = SPStatic.Context(_sharePointSiteUrl)) {

            List sharedDocs = ctx.Web.Lists.GetByTitle(library);

            var query = ctx.LoadQuery(sharedDocs.RootFolder.Folders.Where(fd => fd.Name == name));

            ctx.ExecuteQuery();

            Folder f = query.SingleOrDefault();

            return f != null;

        }

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

There is also a client-callable `Web.GetFileByUrl(string absOrServerRelUrl)` functioning identically to `Web.GetFileByServerRelativeUrl|Path`, but returning a File object with Exist=false (while the others throw explicitly) if the file does not exist.
They all call `SPWeb.GetFile` internally (which is not client-callable), check via ILSpy.